# Unexpected end of declaration - in android AIDE

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

I keep getting "`Unexpected end of declaration`" at the closing brace of the empty constructor. Would someone mind pointing me in the direction of what I'm not understanding? The class is as follows:

```
package info.welltrak.multi.vos;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
* Value object model for drinking water systems.
*/
public class WaterSystemVo implements Serializable
{

    /** Empty constructor. */
    public WaterSystemVo()
    { 
    }

    /** Full constructor. *//
    public WaterSystemVo(int id, String systemId, String systemName)
    {
        mId = id;
        mSystemId = systemId;
        mName = systemName;
    }

    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int mId;
    /** Get record id. */
    public int getId(){ return mId; }
    /** Set record id. */
    public void setId(int id){ mId = id; }

    private String mSystemId;
    /** Get water system id number. */
    public String getSystemId(){ return mSystemId; }
    /** Set water system id number. */
    public void setSystemId(String systemId){ mSystemId = systemId; }

    private String mName;
    /** Get water system name. */
    public String getName(){ return mName; }
    /** Set water system name. */
    public void setName(String name){ mName = name; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra `/` on the comment line:

```
/** Full constructor. *//
```

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
/** Full constructor. *//
```

as below

```
/** Full constructor. */
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javadoc comments as - `/** This is a comment */`   not `/** This is a comment *//`

So Change   `/** Full constructor. *//`  to  `/** Full constructor. */`
i.e.

```
 /** Full constructor. */
        public WaterSystemVo(int id, String systemId, String systemName)
        {
            mId = id;
            mSystemId = systemId;
            mName = systemName;
        }
```

Comment: He obviously understands how to make a comment as he does it correctly  in a whole bunch of places in the rest of the code. I'm guessing it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as fellows are saying: The problem is just a extra slash.

Replace:

```
/** Full constructor. *//
```

With:

```
/** Full constructor. */
```

And try using:

```
// For Single Line Comments
```